# Получение значения переменной и добавление ее в List

Tags: c#, virtual

Мне нужно чтобы я мог в конструкторе базового класса вызвать некий метод.
Он, в свою очередь, взял бы указанное в `MyClass` текущее значение переменной counter
и добавил его в лист `MyObject.Data`.

Комментариями в коде я постарался описать, то что я хочу, но реализовать это мне не удалось.

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private List<int> Data = new();
    // Здесь указать что-то вроде
    // public Action<int> GetValue;
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public MyObject Obj;

    public Base()
    {
        // Здесь указать что-то вроде
        // Obj.GetValue();
    }
}

public class MyClass : Base
{
    int counter = 50;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Obj = new()
        {
            Name = "One",
            // здесь указать что-то вроде
            // GetValue => counter
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А смысл этого всего, если ваш `Action` или любая другая реализация, будет вызвана только раз, при вызове конструктора? Почему тогда сразу через конструктор не передавать нужное (`public MyObject(int value){ Data.Add(value); }` а далее `Obj = new(counter) { ... }`)?

Comment: Этот код немного упрощен. Прошу прошения, что ввел в заблуждение. На самом деле этот делегат должен вызываться в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение своего вопроса

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Data = new List<int>();
    public Func<int> GetValue { get; set; }

    public void AddValue(int value)
    {
        Data.Add(value);
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public MyObject Obj;
    public abstract void Initialize();

    public Base()
    {
        Initialize();
        Obj.AddValue(Obj.GetValue());

        foreach(var a in Obj.Data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : Base
{
    int counter = 50;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Obj = new MyObject
        {
            Name = "One",
            GetValue = () => counter
        };
    }
}
```